# Reading from single table in sql server using multiple threads with sql transaction in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to read records from database table and using multi threads and want to update one filed of table like status. 
How may i do this?
and also make sure that not reading the same records twice in different thread.
Please help!!!

Comment: you should do some reading about database concurrency models: https://www.w3computing.com/sqlserver2012/concurrency-control-concurrency-models/

Comment: Use each thread reads a partition of a table. For example thread, one reads all records its primary key value less than 1000 and another thread reads all records greater or equal to 1000.

Comment: But reading data is continuous process and if every 2 seconds database calls done and found suppose 300 records then i want to create 3 threads and records process parallel.